# The name "IndustryViewModel" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:KPI.CTC.ViewModel"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I was trying to set the DataContext of view through XAML but faced the error that the name does not exist in the provided namespace.

**XAML FILE**

```
<UserControl x:Class="KPI.CTC.UI.Industry"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:KPI.CTC.ViewModel"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:IndustryViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

But when I tried to the same in xaml.cs, it worked perfectly.

**XAML.CS FILE**

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using KPI.CTC.ViewModel;

namespace KPI.CTC.UI {
    public partial class Industry : UserControl {
        public Industry() {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new IndustryViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

**VIEWMODEL Class**

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;

namespace KPI.CTC.ViewModel {
    public class IndustryViewModel : ViewModelBase {

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IndustryViewModel() {
            Name = "MyString";
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please explain why am I not able to set the DataContext through xaml?

Comment: This looks OK. Try rebuilding/reopening the solution. Note: you are setting `UserControl.Resources` instead of `UserControl.DataContext`.

Comment: @user1603970 do you have errors elsewhere in code that stop it from compiling? Are `IndustryViewModel` and `Industry` in the same assembly?

Comment: @amnezjak tried cleaning/rebuilding the soln but no luck.

Comment: @dkozl No I do not have any other errors in the code. `IndustryViewModel` and `Industry` are in different assemblies.

Comment: if they are in different assemblies then try `xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:KPI.CTC.ViewModel;assembly=YourAssemblyName` and see if it helps

Comment: Just to confirm. You've used assembly name as defined in Application tab of properties of the assembly that defines `ViewModel` class (without adding .dll)

Comment: This is how I defined it `xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:KPI.CTC.ViewModel;assembly:KPI.CTC.ViewModel"`. As u can see in the question that the `IndustryViewModel` class is defined in `KPI.CTC.ViewModel` namespace.

Comment: `assembly=` not `assembly:`

Comment: U gotta be kidding me dunno how it worked...I had hardcoded the assembly earlier and this time I selected it from the dropdownlist. Thanks for the help!!